# authentication in wcf Rest

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, rest, odata

I have one solution and it is made of two kind of project one is asp.net and it's using .net membership for authenticate the users
another project is WCF REST (Odata) , how I can authenticate the user in wcf project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

1. The easiest way would be to move the WCF OData service into the ASP.NET project and follow the directions outlined in this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2010/07/21/odata-and-authentication-part-7-forms-authentication.aspx) which talks about Forms Authentication in OData
2. Alternatively you could add a [custom basic authentication module](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2010/07/21/odata-and-authentication-part-6-custom-basic-authentication.aspx) to your OData site that uses the same .NET membership subsystem to check users/passwords etc.

Either way you should check out the [full series of Authentication Blog posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/tags/authentication/) on the Astoria Team blog.

Hope this helps

Alex (OData Program Manager)

Comment: but do you have any sample projects or any suggestion for this?